# Alphanumeric 8 digits unique id for users in C#.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, xml

What I want to do is that I have created a asp.net web application and right now I m using XML to save my data (I AM NOT USING SQL)and my next task is to **Generate A unique 8digits Alphanumeric Id** for the users which will be used by them In future to track there request.
*I have been given a particular format of this ID so I can't use 'GUID'.*
The format given is this:

- PR000000(PR stands for Project)
- NP000000(NP stands for Non-Project)

So, the **first two letters** will be selected according to the user entry(if its a Project procurement request then **'PR'** and in case of Non-project Procurement request **'NP'**) and rest **6 digits** are simple integers which will keep increasing (000001,000002,000003....999999).
I have searched a lot everywhere but its all about php,uniquecode,GUID etc. but I just want a simple code which perform the above task with ease like **IF-Else statement + keep increasing the count(000001...000002..)**.

---

**This is the code for Project and Non project selection:**

```
PROJECT<input type="radio" name="portal" id="radio1" onclick="changeMe(this);"/>  <input       type="text" name="textprojectOff" id="text1" value="Project Name" onclick="changeMe(this);"/>
NON-PROJECT<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="portal" onclick="changeMe(this)"/> &nbsp; <input type="text" name="textnonprojectOff" id="text2" value="Department" onclick="changeMe(this);"/>
<script type="text/javascript"  >
 function changeMe(inField) 
{
    var fieldId = inField.id;
    var type = fieldId.substring(0, 4);

    if (type == 'text') {
        var name = fieldId.substring(4);
        var radioButton = document.getElementById("radio" + name);
        radioButton.checked = true;
    } else {
        var name = fieldId.substring(5);
        var textField = document.getElementById("text" + name);
        textField.focus();
        textField.value ='';
    }
}
```

*If anyone require my xml code for my help then kindly tell me in the comment section I will post it at that time.*

Comment: Keep a self incremental number for the Integer and append it with the default input by the user

Comment: My first suggestion would be to not do this exclusively in javascript, but in the backend. If anyone manages to either change the fields (via the F12 console), or has disabled javascript in his browser; you'd get issues. Code behind is where you want to do that, you can always relay the created ID back to the user after you're sure that's the ID that's actually in the database.

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee- Can u plzzz show me how to do it?? or any link relevant to it?? That will be a greahelp.

Comment: @Flater-hey thanks for ur suggestion but m not doing the ID generation stuff in JavaScript...this is just for the radio buttons and text boxes...and definitely I will do code behind for my this query. If you have any code for it then plzzz tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I got the solution of My Own problem ,So,I thought to share it with everyone so that other can get help from it.  **Without Using any typical Function I have generated an Unique Id for each and ever user.**
**.cs programming:**

```
 protected void GetId()
    {
        MSXML2.DOMDocument objXML = new MSXML2.DOMDocument();
        string oPath = null;
        oPath = Server.MapPath("PARNId.xml");
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        if (objXML.load(oPath) == true)
        {
            objNextId = objXML.selectSingleNode("//Id").text;

        }
    }

    protected void SetId()
    {
        MSXML2.DOMDocument objXML = new MSXML2.DOMDocument();
        string oPath = null;

        oPath = Server.MapPath("PARNId.xml");
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        if (objXML.load(oPath) == true)
        {
            objXML.selectSingleNode("//Id").text = objNextId;
        }
        if (RadioButton2.Checked == true)
        {
            Label1.Text = "Your PURCHASE ACTION REQUEST NUMBER Is : PR" + objNextId;

        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = "Your PURCHASE ACTION REQUEST NUMBER Is :NP" + objNextId;
        }
        objXML.save(oPath);
    }
```

**Calling both the functions**

```
GetId();
        Label1.Text = objNextId;
        objNextId = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(objNextId) + 1);
        SetId()
```

*I have created a separate XML file named Track.xml, in which I have assigned a node 100000,and this keep incrementing with every request made and finally I saved the label1.text and this keep record of all PARN generated with each user*  Hope it helps other!!

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, you will have to generate the unique ids from server-side code after checking the existing values in a Database.

you can use a Oracle Sequence if you want. Client side generation should not be used in this case because there is a change that multiple users can get the same unique id. So this generation should be handled server side / db side.

Comment: any link or example regarding this will be a great help??@Ashish